# using distinct in select having joins with multiple table

Tags: sql-server, join, distinct

Trying to use Distinct in select statement but not getting the desired result. I want CaseID to be returned for the last updated comment only. Below is the query that I am trying to use.

```
Select Distinct av.CaseID,fr.Rule_Description, av.Date, av.Status, fr.RULE_PRIORITY, ac.User_comments, max(ac.Comment_PostDate),ac.UserID
From tblAlertView av
Join tblAlertComment ac
on  av.CaseID = ac.CaseID
Join tblFBLRule fr
on  av.RuleID = fr.Rule_ID
Join TBLUSER usr
on ac.UserID = usr.USERID

group by av.CaseID, fr.Rule_Description, av.Date, av.Status, fr.RULE_PRIORITY, ac.User_comments, ac.Comment_PostDate,ac.UserID
```

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yd6k.jpg)

Comment: as mentioned by @Pream remove the `ac.Comment_PostDate` from `group by` clause, as this will give you multiple results and the `MAX()` aggregation will not work work as expected. When you use the `group by`, you do not need `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
ac.Comment_PostDate
```

from group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `JOIN` to get to `tblAlertComment`, if you use `CROSS APPLY` you can specify to just return the top 1 comment per case:

```
SELECT  av.CaseID, 
        fr.Rule_Description, 
        av.Date, 
        av.Status, 
        fr.RULE_PRIORITY, 
        ac.User_comments, 
        ac.Comment_PostDate,
        ac.UserID
FROM    tblAlertView AS av
        INNER JOIN tblFBLRule AS fr
            ON av.RuleID = fr.Rule_ID
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 ac.User_comments, ac.Comment_PostDate, ac.UserID
            FROM    tblAlertComment AS ac
                    INNER JOIN tblUser AS usr
                        ON usr.UserID = ac.UserID
            WHERE   ac.CaseID = av.CaseID
            ORDER BY ac.Comment_PostDate DESC
        ) AS ac;
```